# How to show saved image from document directory by getting path through sqlite in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiimageview

I have saved images in document directory and saved its path in data base successfully now I am not getting that how to show that image in my image view?

Should I use query to select only path?

Will it automatically pick the image from directory?

Or should I use code for load image in my view where I want to show image.

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *strimagename;
    strimagename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test.jpg"];
    thumbFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:strimagename];
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    NSLog(@"image path: %@ ", [MyCommonFunctions saveImageInDocuments:image]); 
    imageSelect.image = image;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     NSLog(@"image saved %@",image);
}
```

This above code is for saving.

---

By using this code in i get this log message for image:

```
2012-12-08 20:40:30.450 loginApp[757:c07] CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL WITH DB 
2012-12-08 20:41:05.371 loginApp[757:c07] image path: 08412012084105.png 
2012-12-08 20:41:05.378 loginApp[757:c07] image saved <UIImage: 0x926da00>
```

Success Query:

```
insert into login(Name,Email,Password,DOB,image) values('hamesh', 'hamesh@hamesh.com','hamesh','2012-12-09 04:40:57 +0000','<UIImageView: 0x926d8f0; frame = (139 219; 133 115); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x926d950>>')
```

here i am using code that build  Sql,in image should i give property NSString? or imageView?

```
- (IBAction)registerbtn:(id)sender {
    DBHandler *db =[[DBHandler alloc]init];

        if([self validateForm])
        {
            if([self validateEmailWithString:txtEmail.text])
            {
                if ([db authenticateRegistration:txtName.text andEmail:txtEmail.text andPassword:txtPassword.text andDob:txtDob.text andImage:imageSelect])
                {
                    UIAlertView *loginalert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"  Congrats" message:@"SignUp Success" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [loginalert show];
                                }
                else
                { 
 UIAlertView *loginalert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"  Try Again!" message:@"SignUp Failure" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [loginalert show];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: by using this code in  i get this log message for image    2012-12-08 20:40:30.450 loginApp[757:c07] CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL WITH DB
2012-12-08 20:41:05.371 loginApp[757:c07] image path: 08412012084105.png 
2012-12-08 20:41:05.378 loginApp[757:c07] image saved <UIImage: 0x926da00>


Success Query: insert into login(Name,Email,Password,DOB,image) values('hamesh', 'hamesh@hamesh.com','hamesh','2012-12-09 04:40:57 +0000','<UIImageView: 0x926d8f0; frame = (139 219; 133 115); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x926d950>>')

Comment: see my log message after sucessful connection with db is this not image path?

Comment: I put your `NSLog` stuff in your question so I could read it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your updated question that includes the `NSLog` statements, it appears that your `NSLog` of `[MyCommonFunctions saveImageInDocuments:image]` is correct. But you also show us the SQL that you're generating, and it is obviously not using that `[MyCommonFunctions saveImageInDocuments:image]` for the last parameter, but rather you're obviously accidentally grabbing a `UIImageView`. Look at your code that is building that SQL. Update your question with that code that builds your SQL if the solution doesn't leap out at you.

Comment: i did also with NSString in place of imageView but thronging exception

Comment: @QualityCoder If it's throwing an exception, it could be because your `NSString` variable was not set properly and is `nil`, for example. Looks like you're calling `[MyCommonFunctions saveImageInDocuments:image]`, but I don't see where you're saving the filename that that returns. You need to put that filename in a `NSString` for future reference, an ivar that you'll use when you call `authenticateRegistration`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `imageWithContentsOfFile` class method of `UIImage`.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePathFromDB];
```